# How can free Interface implemented class?

Tags: delphi, class, object, interface, free

I have a little problem. As the title says I want to release an object whose class implements an interface, however I get an error **"invalid pointer operation"**.

My Interface:

```
Interface

Type
  // An interface definition
  IMessageEvents = Interface(IInterface)
    ['{BD27EFC6-CC9A-437A-A8B8-16F722518836}']

    Procedure messageReceived(messageData: String);
  End;

Implementation
```

My Class:

```
Type
  TChatManager = Class(TInterfacedObject, IMessageEvents)
  Private
  Protected
    Procedure messageReceived(messageData: String); Overload;
  Public
    Constructor Create; Overload;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
    Procedure connect;
    Procedure disconnect;
  End;

Implementation

Constructor TChatManager.Create;
Begin
    { ....... }
End;

Procedure TChatManager.connect;
Begin
  { ....... }
End;

Procedure TChatManager.disconnect;
Begin
  { ....... }
End;

Procedure TChatManager.messageReceived(messageData: String);
Begin
  { ....... }
End;

Destructor TChatManager.Destroy;
Begin
  Inherited Destroy;
End;
```

My Code:

```
 self.chatMng := TChatManager.Create;
 self.chatMng.Free;
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code that's using the interface that displays the problem.  From what you've shown so far, nothing looks wrong, but at a wild guess it could be a double-free problem.

Comment: @afrazier I don't doing nothing special. I simply instantiate the object and then attempt to free it. Obviously is a double free problem but not attempt to free the object nowhere more.

Comment: What type of variable is `chatMng`?  `TChatManager` or `IMessageEvents`?  Is `Self`'s destructor or `OnDestroy` trying to free `chatMng` if it's assigned?

Comment: The "self.chatMng" is TChatManager type. I've also tried to check if the object is assigned, I mean, if different from NIL. Indeed I get it different from Nil, but when trying to unlock, I jump that mistake.

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa Hmm, you might want to take that back. You did not show the declaration of `chatMng`. So its type cannot be definitely determined from your question. At the very least it could be any superclass of `TChatManager`. What it needs to be is an interface type.

Comment: David Heffernan you're right. @afrazier sorry.

Comment: Also, freeing `chatMng` isn't going to set it to `nil`.  Checking `Assigned(chatMng)` will still return `True` after calling `chatMng.Free`.  If you're going to reuse `chatMng`, then you need to make sure to set it to `nil` after calling `.Free` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that `chatMng` is of type `TChatManager`. That can be deduced by the fact that you assign `TChatManager.Create` to it, and call `Free` on it.

However, `TChatManager` derives from `TInterfacedObject`. That means that its lifetime is controlled by the references that are taken to its interfaces. When the final reference is released, the object is destroyed.

The rule of thumb is that if you derive from `TInterfacedObject` then you must never take a reference to the object other than through an interface variable.

Steps to correct your code:

1. Change `chatMng` to be of type `IMessageEvents`.
2. Remove the call to `chatMng.Free` which the compiler will object to in any case.

Comment: Thanks for response but how can i do explicit destroy of object ?

Comment: The object is destroyed when the final reference to it is released. So, `chatMng := nil` would do the trick if nothing else held a reference. Generally you don't explicitly destroy reference counted objects.

Comment: I thought the interface reference counting only happened when dealing with interface variables?  That said, if the OP is passing the object to something requesting the interface, it's going to increment the refcount and decrement back to zero in that something and free the object.

Comment: I  would suspect that he's getting the gpf because chatMng is of type IMessageEvents...  if your going to put in a reference...then you don't free it...If you put it in an object...then you free it if you don't get a reference from it...

Comment: @House No. That would be a compile error on the call to Free. The comments to the Q confirm my supposition.

Comment: ahhh...didn't catch the compiler part...you're right that the compiler will belch on the free

Answer (score 1):

He must not be showing us all the code...because what he shows should not cause a GPF...you can create a TInterfacedObject and free it...if you don't get a reference to it...but If you get a Reference you are no longer in charge of freeing it...

Here's the Interface

```
unit Unit3;



Interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

Type
  // An interface definition
  IMessageEvents = Interface(IInterface)
    ['{BD27EFC6-CC9A-437A-A8B8-16F722518836}']

    Procedure messageReceived(messageData: String);
  End;



Type
  TChatManager = Class(TInterfacedObject, IMessageEvents)
  Private
    FStrings: TStrings;
  Protected
    Procedure messageReceived(messageData: String); Overload;
    procedure UpdateStatus(aString: string);
  Public
    Constructor Create(aStrings: TStrings); 
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
    Procedure connect;
    Procedure disconnect;
  End;

Implementation

Constructor TChatManager.Create(aStrings: TStrings);
Begin
    { ....... }
   FStrings := aStrings;
   UpdateStatus('Created');
   Connect;
End;

Procedure TChatManager.connect;
Begin
  { ....... }
    UpdateStatus('Connected');
End;

Procedure TChatManager.disconnect;
Begin
  { ....... }
  UpdateStatus('DisConnected');
End;

Procedure TChatManager.messageReceived(messageData: String);
Begin
  { ....... }
   UpdateStatus('Message Received');
   UpdateStatus(messageData);
End;

procedure TChatManager.UpdateStatus(aString: string);
begin
  FStrings.Add(aString);
  FStrings.Add('RefCount: '+ IntToStr(Self.RefCount));
end;

Destructor TChatManager.Destroy;
Begin
   Disconnect;
   UpdateStatus('Destroyed');
  Inherited Destroy;


End;

end.
```

Here's the form

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, unit3, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
   { Private declarations }
   chatMng: TChatManager;
   iChatMng: IMessageEvents;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
type
  THackManager= class(TChatManager);

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  chatMng := TChatManager.Create(Memo1.Lines);
  THackManager(ChatMng).messageReceived('Hello World from Button1');
  chatMng.Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  iChatMng :=  TChatManager.Create(Memo1.Lines);
  iChatMng.messageReceived('Hello World from Button2');
  iChatMng := nil;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChatMng :=  TChatManager.Create(Memo1.Lines);
 (ChatMng as IMessageEvents).messageReceived('Hello World from Button3');
 //you can't call ChatMng...it's gone  bye bye...
 //ChatMng.Free; //this will cause a GPF if you call free
end;

procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a_IChatMng: IMessageEvents;
begin

  ChatMng :=  TChatManager.Create(Memo1.Lines);
  a_IChatMng := chatMng;
 (ChatMng as IMessageEvents).messageReceived('Hello World from Button4');
 a_IChatMng.messageReceived('Hello World again from Button4');
 //ChatMng.Free; //this will cause a GPF if you call free
end;

end.
```

Here's the dfm

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 326
  Top = 94
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 292
  ClientWidth = 581
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 40
    Top = 200
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 40
    Top = 32
    Width = 411
    Height = 129
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 160
    Top = 200
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button2'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Left = 272
    Top = 200
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button3'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = Button3Click
  end
  object Button4: TButton
    Left = 376
    Top = 200
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button4'
    TabOrder = 4
    OnClick = Button4Click
  end
end
```

Comment: Clearly. Obviously nobody writes just:  self.chatMng := TChatManager.Create;  self.chatMng.Free; In between an interface reference is taken. Also just because you don't see EInvalidPointer does not mean somebody else won't. Depends on memory manager and luck.

Comment: @David They do if they are just creating a proof of concept...like my code...it's not production ready...but does show proof of how things work...

Comment: I'm agreeing with you. It is evident that not all of the code has been shown. Omitted is the section between the create and the free that takes the reference.